# Export PDF and supress page breaks

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, reporting-services

When I export my report to pdf, appear me weird page breaks.
If a lengthy report, that happens to me is that if a table does not fit in the remaining space of a page, it automatically passes me to the page below, thus creating blanks spaces.

Already have enabled the property **Keep Together**, **interactive size** to 0 and i unchecked **keep together on one page if possible** in tablix properties.

However I think the problem is not in the table, because before that, I have a textbox with a title, and is between the table and the textbox that makes page break.

I have already put the textbox and table inside a rectangle, but still have this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the *problem*, exactly? If something doesn't fit on a page it'll go to the next; that's expected behavior, right? Realize that we don't have access to your report, it's kind of hard to imagine the context for your question.

Comment: It was not an expected behavior because half of the table could be on the first page and the rest on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Q: is the table / text box that responsible for the page break issue is inside a Subreport ?

If so, then this is your problem (unless you make a call that this table will always be short enough to stay in single page).

You have to understand: the subreport is the cause for the breaking, the table will not split because it is presented by the sub-report that has to stay in one piece.

The options are:

1. Stay with the subreport - but make sure that the table Maximum length will still fit the Page that the sub-report is lay in it.
2. take out the table from the subreport and place it directly in the main report - that way when the table too long to stay in single page, it will split into two pages.

Comment: In my sub-report have a table and I was watching and I don't find page break.
I really need to have sub-reports. There is no other way possible.

Comment: Then this is your problem. Because the subreport must be in single page, and if the table is too long the subreport will be move to the next page.

Comment: I also read that this type of problem would already be solved in ssrs 2008